# ItemUpdated event not firing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, event-receivers

I have this code where only `ItemAdding` is firing when I add new item in the list but `ItemUpdated` doesn't fire. I am expeting that when new item is added then first `ItemAdding` fires (which is working) and then `ItemUpdated` is fired (which is not working).

`ItemUpdated` only fires after item has been created and then I manually edit record.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   if (properties.ListTitle == "MyList")
   {
      base.ItemAdding(properties);
      properties.AfterProperties["Department"] = "Information Technology";
   }
}

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   //some code here
}
```

In `elements.xml` file I have written following for both events but no luck. Even if I remove this line then it still doesn't work.

```
<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that one of these is true:

- New solution was not deployed correctly
- The event receive is not registered correctly

The first step is to conirm that you have event receiver registered. To do it:

- Install [SP Insider chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj?hl=en)
- Navigate to your SharePoint site
- Click SP Insider extension:

[image]

- Click Find current web
- Locate EventReceivers for your list/library

[image]

- Verify that A) Event receiver exinsts and B) It has correct Synchronization type